# How to use docker to generate grpc code based on go.mod versions?

Tags: docker, go, protocol-buffers, grpc, protoc

Using the official `golang` docker image, I can use the `protoc` command to generate the `x.pb.go` and `x_grpc.pb.go` files. The problem is that it uses the latest versions, while I want to generate those using whichever version that is part of the `go.mod` file.

I tried to start from the `golang` image, then get my project's `go.mod` file, get the dependencies and try to generate from there. Here is my dockerfile:

```
FROM golang:1.15

WORKDIR /app

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt install -y protobuf-compiler

COPY go.* .
RUN go mod download
RUN go get all

RUN export PATH="$PATH:$(go env GOPATH)/bin"

RUN mkdir /api
```

Then I try to bind the volume of the `.proto` file and the `/pb` folder to output them, and use the `protoc` command again (I'm trying directly from the docker right now). Something like this:

```
protoc --proto_path=/api --go_out=/pb --go-grpc_out=/pb /api/x.proto
```

I'm getting this error though:

```
protoc-gen-go: program not found or is not executable
--go_out: protoc-gen-go: Plugin failed with status code 1.
```

My `go.sum` file has `google.golang.org/protobuf v1.25.0` in it, so how come it is not found?

Comment: Have you tried to execute the command `go install google.golang.org/protobuf/cmd/protoc-gen-go` inside the Dockerfile as described in the doc [here](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/go-generated)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`go.mod` & `go.sum` are used for versioning when building `go` programs. This is not what you need here. You want the `protoc` compiler to use the correct plugin versions when running it against your `.proto` file(s).

To install the desired `protoc-gen-go` (and `protoc-gen-go-grpc` if using gRPC) plugins, install them directly. Update your `Dockerfile` like so:

```
FROM golang:1.15

WORKDIR /app

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt install -y protobuf-compiler

RUN GO111MODULE=on \
        go get google.golang.org/protobuf/cmd/protoc-gen-go@v1.25.0 \
        google.golang.org/grpc/cmd/protoc-gen-go-grpc@v1.1.0

# export is redundant here `/go/bin` is already in `golang` image's path
# (and actual any env change here is lost once the command completes)
# RUN export PATH="$PATH:$(go env GOPATH)/bin"

RUN mkdir /api
```

If you want the latest versions of either plugin, either use `@latest` - or drop the `@` suffix